# snowflake external table from a list of jsons

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

got a file.json in my s3 bucket, it contains a list of jsons,
for instance when I download it and parse it with python json load I get a list:

```
[{'k': 'calendar#event'}, {'k': 'calendar#event'}]\
```

loading it into an external table works:

```
create external table if not exists TEST_111
with location = @TESt111
auto_refresh = true
file_format = (type = json);
```

but instead of getting a table with 2 rows, I get one row with a list in it,
any ideas?

Comment: When you create an external table the data is stored in a single VARIANT column, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html#create-external-table). Also, have a look at optional parameters and example provided for semi-structured data [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html#optional-parameters).

Comment: Have you tried using STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE  in your file format options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is provided as array then `strip_outer_array` could be used:

```
create external table if not exists TEST_111
with location = @TESt111
auto_refresh = true
file_format = (type = json, STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY=TRUE);
```

Additionally if the json keys are known in advance, they could be exposed as columns directly in external table's definition:

```
create external table if not exists TEST_111
(
    filename    TEXT  metadata$filename
   ,k           TEXT  AS (value:"k"::TEXT)
)
with location = @TESt111
auto_refresh = true
file_format = (type = json, STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY=TRUE);
```